# Prevent from going to 'Add Books' after pressing the submit button on 'Update Books'

Tags: javascript, php, html

Whenever I press submit button on the 'Update Books', the page goes to the first div which is the 'Add Books'. Is there a way for the page to be still in the 'update books' div?

Here is the picture of 'Add Books'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmyno.jpg

And here is the picture of 'Update Books'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga22O.jpg

```
<div class="updateCont_search">
    <form onsubmit="clicked()" action="content/addBooks.php" method="get">
    <input type="name" name="bookSearch" placeholder="Input Book Details">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="updateCont_searched">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Book ID</th>
    <th>Book Name</th>
    <th>Book Author</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        $bookSearch = '%'.$_GET['bookSearch'].'%';
        $query = "SELECT book_id, book_name, book_author, id_no FROM books WHERE book_id LIKE '%".$bookSearch."%' OR book_name LIKE '%".$bookSearch."%' OR book_author LIKE '%".$bookSearch."%' ORDER BY book_id ASC;";$stmt = $conn->query($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $arr = $stmt->fetchAll();
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td><button><a href='content/addBooks.php?bookSearch=".$arr[$i][3]."' target='_blank'>View</a></button></td>";
        print "<td>".$arr[$i][0]."</td>";
        print "<td>".$arr[$i][1]."</td>";
        print "<td>".$arr[$i][2]."</td>";
        print "</tr>";
        }
        }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var opt = document.getElementsByClassName('titleOption');
    var addBook = document.getElementsByClassName('addCont');
    var updBook = document.getElementsByClassName('updateCont');
    var addCont = addBook[0];
    var updateCont = updBook[0];
    var add = opt[0];
    var upd = opt[1];

    function clicked(){
        window.onbeforeload = function(){
            upd.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(51,51,51)';
            add.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,100,100)';
            updateCont.style.display = 'block';
            addCont.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: The font on that site makes me want to carve my eyes out of my head. Please just paste your code in here

Comment: I'm very sorry, I am new here. I don't know how to edit but I hope it's okay. This is the best I've got so far.

Answer (score 0):

let me get this straight, you want to go to back to update book page after pressing submit? User php header

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes sir, but the problem is they both are in the same page. They are just in different divs where the clicked has a display of block and the other is displayed as none. I've tried the said Javascript, but it didn't work.